# Hive UDFs, Java Primitives and null

Tags: java, hive, user-defined-functions

On page 168 of Programming Hive by E. Capriolo et al it states "...in Java primitives are not objects and cannot be null." So, for the simple Hive UDF:

```
public class ConvertToCelcius extends UDF {
    public double evaluate(double value) {
        return (value - 32) / 1.8;
      }
}
```

what happens if a null row value is encountered?

Also, using a Java primitive how can we test whether or not a null is passed to our UDF?

Presumably, we could rewrite the above as:

```
public class ConvertToCelcius extends UDF {
    public Double evaluate(Double value) {
        if (value == null) {
          return null;
        }
        return (value - 32) / 1.8;
      }
}
```

Comment: "*what happens if a null row value is encountered?*" => a compile error - it's not possible to do that. Unless you pass a `Double` in which case you will get a NPE.

Comment: Compile error or runtime error? The above code with "double" compiles fine.

Comment: What I mean is you can't call `evaluate(null)` on the first method: compile error. And if you pass a `Double d = null` at runtime, you will get a NullPointerException.

Comment: This is the whole point behind my question. "evaluate(double value)" compiles fine, can be packaged into a jar and used in a script but what happens when a null value is passed? And that's a "double" and NOT a "Double". It is perfectly valid and legal to use type "double".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create UDF with primitives data type only and check null value in sql Case Statement

ie

```
select 
      CASE WHEN columnName = null then null 
               else evaluate(columnName) end columnName
 From tabelName
```

Note : evaluate Is UDF name.

Comment: "...We can create UDF with primitives data type only..." I don't think this is correct. I have several UDFs with lists of doubles (eg List<Double>) and they work fine. However, I see your point about having to test for null at the query side so as to not pass a null to a Java primitive.

Comment: @user25029 This ( eg List<Double>) thing is workin due to  java  boxing and unboxing feature  more detail.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: I agree but my point was that List<Double> is NOT a primitive.